# API violation when using waitForExpectations

Tags: ios, testing

I'm running a UI test where I need to test an asynchronous function using the `waitForExpectations` API.

I'm getting this error:

> "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "API violation - call made to wait without any expectations having been set."

I really don't understand, as I have correctly created the expectation.

Also, there seems to be a documentation bug: according to the documentation the API is `expectation(description:)` but the compiler won't accept that, instead I need to use `XCTestExpectation()` to create one.

```
 func testExample() {
    XCTAssertTrue(state == .STATE_NOT_READY)
    let exp1 = XCTestExpectation()

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "net.tech4freedom.AppTest")
    let delay: DispatchTimeInterval = .seconds((2))
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        XCTAssertTrue(true)
        exp1.fulfill()
    }

    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 4){ [weak self] error in
        print("X: async expectation")
        XCTAssertTrue(true)
    }
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10.0, handler: nil)
}
```

Comment: What error do you get when you use `self.expectation(description:)`? Because this would be the correct way to do this, otherwise your test class doesn't know that you created your expectation.

Comment: If I try to create the expectation with the description parameter(     let exp1 = XCTestExpectation(description: "ss2")   ) ,  I get "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Answer (score 45):

Ok, your mistake is that you try to instantiate the expectation directly. The docs clearly say

> Use the following **XCTestCase methods** to create XCTestExpectation instances:
>   - expectation(description:)

This means, that you should create expectations like this :

```
func testMethod() {
    let exp = self.expectation(description: "myExpectation")
    // your test code
}
```

Comment: You could also call the API `wait(for expectations: [XCTestExpectation], timeout seconds: TimeInterval)` and pass in the expectations if they originate from some testing stub class.

Comment: You're my saver...Thank you so much!!

Comment: @DeanKelly I would upvote your answer, that is what helped me